# If a table is fed to the DataTable() constructor, can I get the DataTable instance from the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working with a large legacy application. It uses the DataTables jQuery plugin, and at some point -- somewhere -- a DataTable is created, impacting the content of a table whose ID I know.

Unfortunately, I cannot easily find where in the application the DataTable is being defined. I've grepped all over the place for the string `new DataTable(`, and I simply cannot locate it.

So my question is this: If I want to apply a callback to an event -- in this case, the `draw` event -- on my DataTable, is there a way I can get the DataTable instance from the table DOM object itself?

Here's what I've tried (which does not work, as there is no property called `dataTable`):

```
var myTable = $('#myTable')[0];
var myDataTableInstance = myTable.dataTable;
myTable.on('draw', function () {
    console.log('Redraw occurred at: ' + new Date().getTime());
});
```

I'm assuming there might be a way to do this. I'm just not seeing it when I dump out `myTable` in the console.

Comment: "*grepped for new DataTable*" - there's different ways to initialise datatables, see : https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: To add an event to a "datatable", you add the event to the DOM element, so your question of how to add the `draw` event is just `$("#myTable").on("draw", function() [` at which point `this` will be the `table` and `$(this).DataTable()` will be the datatable.   https://jsfiddle.net/4x65mpnk/

Comment: *Is there a way I can get the DataTable instance from the table* `$('#myTable').DataTable()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable().on('draw', function () {
            console.log('Redraw occurred at: ' + new Date().getTime());
        });
    });
```

This appears to work well.